# How do I fix this drill hole on countertop?

Tags: repair

How should I go about fixing this mistake I made? The size of the hole is 5/32 in diameter and about a 1/16 deep. I’m thinking of cutting a piece of laminate from behind the fridge and hole punching out a circle  the same size. Not sure what the best way to adhere it would be. Should I do multiple punch outs to get the right height? Or should I fill it with something? Any help would be awesome. Thanks.
[image: 5/32 drill hole]

Comment: You fail to say what the countertop is made of, but I'm guessing it's plastic laminate ("Formica").

Answer (score 3):

That's a tough one because plastic laminate is applied to the particle board substrate with contact cement, which is soft and rubbery. It's very good for large areas, but lousy for little fixes like that. To make matters worse, you need to remove the existing adhesive before carrying on.

If you can indeed get a repair disc from a hidden area, here's what I'd do:

1. Clean out this hole by drilling *deeper*... just enough to completely remove the old adhesive. You could also scrape it away with a square-ended hobby knife or whatever.
2. Remove the adhesive from your repair disc. The simplest way might be to rub the disc on a piece of sandpaper until it's clean.
3. Test fit the disc. Figure out the best orientation with respect to pattern-matching.
4. Set the disc with clear two-part epoxy or wood glue. The key here is going to be to get the patch on plane. See the glare in your photo? If you don't get the patch on plane it'll reflect differently and appear much darker or lighter than the surrounding area. Set it in the adhesive and periodically adjust it as the adhesive sets using a toothpick or hobby knife.
5. After the initial set has cured and the disc is stable, fill the circular joint with more epoxy or glue to seal it up and improve the appearance. Be prepared to wipe excess off the surface before it cures.
6. Once that's done, buff the area lightly with something suitable (like steel wool) to knock off any bumps or edges and make the sheen uniform. Be very careful here to not leave a large marred area. Test somewhere hidden and inspect your work often. This step could ruin the outcome.

Answer (score 3):

The laminate companies make a material to create a seam between 2 sheets. I would get that and fill. It will have a slight difference in color but trying to patch laminate will usually show no matter how good you are the small tube to fill a seam may be a better solution than a plug.

Answer (score 1):

Try super glue and baking soda.
Put a tape at the bottom of the hole from below. 
Then pour little baking soda and then few drops if super glue.
Once that sets pour little more baking soda and then add few drops of super glue and likt that built it up till hole gets filled. Super glue reaction with baking soda makes hard like rock. Watch this on YouTube.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Thanks for the answer; keep 'em coming. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to contribute here.

Answer (score 0):

That small of a spot, I would use lacquer burn in sticks. You can blend the colors to match a good "middle ground" color, by heating it up with a heat gun or butane lighter. Drip the hot mix into the hole till filled. Slick it off with a slightly hotter than warm putty knife to knock off most of the excess and clean the rest of the smear off with lacquer thinner.

In my opinion, trying to get a small patch in that size of a hole will be more obvious than a mono-color filler done in the right color.